# Modify WooCommerce email shipping text value

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm attempting to use the 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display' filter to show 'Free' in the WooCommerce email table when no shipping charges will be incurred. In the image, I'm trying to get the 'Free' and 'Flat Rate' values to just show as free. My PHP is only moderate, but I can't get my code quite there. Does anyone see what I could be missing?

```
/* return custom text on email when shipping is free */
function filter_email_shipping_text( $shipping ) {
    if ( $this->order_shipping != 0) ) {
      $shipping = __( 'Free!', 'woocommerce' );
      return $shipping;
    } else {
      return $shipping;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display', 'filter_email_shipping_text', 1 );
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the extra ")" from the 3rd line; it should be: `if ( $this->order_shiping != 0 ) {`

Comment: My mistake with the extra ")". But something else is wrong with my function. It doesn't filter the shipping value and, for some reason, breaks the actual email. When the function is in place, and I resend a processing email, instead of resending, it opens in the same browser window without anything below the main email body table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED IT**

I was able to fix my function and it now works how intended. This is the working function and filter in case anyone wants to use. This will return custom text when flat rate shipping is free.

```
/* return custom text on email when shipping is free */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display', 'filter_email_shipping_text', 10, 2 );

function filter_email_shipping_text( $shipping, $order_id ) {
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  if ( $order->order_shipping == 0 ) {
    $shipping = sprintf(__( 'Free!', 'woocommerce' ));
  }
  return $shipping;
}
```